# How to group by geospatial attribute in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a set of documents in mongodb and I am trying to group the document set using the nearest geopoint coordinates within distance of 100m radius to a given document, and get the average value of `type` and the `$first` value for `cordinates`. A sample document set is as below.  Is there a way to do this using existing functions in mongodb aggregation pipeline or do I have to use newly introduced `$function` to build a custom aggregation function. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e790cfe46fa8260f41d2626"},
  "cordinates":[103.96277219999999,1.3437526],
  "timestamp":1584991486436,
  "user":{"$oid":"5e4bbbc31eac8e2e3ca219a6"},
  "type": 1,
  "__v":0}

{"_id":{"$oid":"5e790d7346fa8260f41d2627"},
  "cordinates":[103.97242539965999,1.33508],
  "timestamp":1584991603400,
  "user":{"$oid":"5e4bbbc31eac8e2e3ca219a6"},
  "type": 1,
  "__v":0}

 {"_id":{"$oid":"5e790d7346fa8260f41d2627"},
  "cordinates":[103.97242539990099,1.33518],
  "timestamp":1584991603487,
  "user":{"$oid":"5e4bbbc31eac8e2e3ca219a6"},
  "type": 2,
  "__v":0}
```

A sample document that would be expected as output after aggregation pipeline.

```
 {"avgCordinates":[103.97242539990099,1.33518],
  "avgType": 1.6,
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed solve this by by building a custom function to represent a single value for the geospatial coordinate and then grouping by the returned values. I was able to group nearby coordinates to a single document as the function I used to transform values would also map to nearby scalar values. So far it has given me expected outputs for the heatmap. But still I'm not sure this is the correct way to do this. There should be a better answer for this. I have posted my aggregation pipeline below. Any suggestions for improving this are appreciated.

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'timestamp': {
        '$gte': 1599889338000
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$addFields': {
      'singleCoordinate': {
        '$function': {
          'body': 'function(coordinates){return ((coordinates[1]+90)*180+coordinates[0])*1000000000000;}', 
          'args': [
            '$coordinates', '$geonear'
          ], 
          'lang': 'js'
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        '$subtract': [
          '$singleCoordinate', {
            '$mod': [
              '$singleCoordinate', 100
            ]
          }
        ]
      }, 
      'coordinates': {
        '$first': '$coordinates'
      }, 
      'avgType': {
        '$avg': '$type'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$addFields': {
      'latitude': {
        '$arrayElemAt': [
          '$coordinates', 1
        ]
      }, 
      'longitude': {
        '$arrayElemAt': [
          '$coordinates', 0
        ]
      }, 
      'weight': {
        '$multiply': [
          '$avgType', '$_id'
        ]
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      '_id': false, 
      'coordinates': false, 
      'avgType': false
    }
  }
]
```